# Does there exist a nonmeager compact subset of an infinite-dimensional Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, baire-category

Let $ X $ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space and let $ K \subset X $ be compact. If $ K $ is contained in a finite dimensional subspace of $ X $, then $ K $ must be meager. However, there may exist compact subsets of $ X $ that cannot be contained in a finite-dimensional subspace of $ X $. Can they be nonmeager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $K$ has any interior points then there is a closed ball inside it. The closed ball would then be compact and that makes the space finite dimensional. Hence, $K$ is actually a nowhere dense set in $X$.